# Can't store stuff in object

Tags: r

I'm very new to R, but haven't had trouble storing values until now. I'm trying to take the values of the second column in 'data' and store them in symbolList in the format they are currently in(in quotes, comma separated). Thank you!

```
library(quantmod)
symbolList <- c("DLX", "SWK", "AGN", "SKX", "GE", "ZOES", "NVCR", "FRT", "ENLK", "PYPL", "TXMD", "PLAY", "NWL", 
            "JAH")
## ALTERNATIVE symbolList <-        paste(c("'",paste(d[,2],collapse="','"),"'"),collapse="")
## ALTERNATIVE symbolList <- c(cat(paste(shQuote(( d[,2]), type="cmd"),   collapse=", ")))

results <- NULL
for (ii in symbolList){
data1 <- getSymbols(Symbols = ii, 
                  src = "yahoo", 
                  from = Sys.Date() - 150, 
                  auto.assign = FALSE)
de = head(data1,100)
colnames(de) <- c("open","high","low","close","volume","adj.")
overnightRtn <- (as.numeric(de[2:nrow(de),"open"])/as.numeric(de[1:  (nrow(de)-1),"close"])) - 1

results <- rbind(results,cbind(
paste(round(sum(overnightRtn,na.rm=TRUE),2),"%",sep="")))
} 
colnames(results) <- c("overnightRtn")
rownames(results) <- symbolList

View(results)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several things here.
If you want to store the content of a `data.frame character` column in a `vector` variable, just do

```
symbolList <- data[,2]
```

If you want to store the whole `character` column, all in one only space-separated `character` variable, then do

```
symbolList <- paste(data[,2],collapse=" ")
```

But then they will be space-separated.
If you want to to store the whole `character` column, all quoted in one only comma-separated `character` variable, then try

```
symbolList <- paste(c("'",paste(data[,2],collapse="','"),"'"),collapse="")
```

`cat` is an output function.
`shQuote` (from `?shQuote`) "Quote a string to be passed to an operating system shell", I am not sure why you would need that now.

**EDIT** :
If you want to to store the whole `character` column, all **double**-quoted in one only comma-separated `character` variable, then do:

```
toto <- letters[1:3] # Define a character vector
symbolList <- paste(c("\"",paste(toto,collapse="\",\""),"\""),collapse="")
symbolList
#[1] "\"a\",\"b\",\"c\""
cat(symbolList)
#"a","b","c"
```

Now, I have to say that from my experience, it is very unlikely that any function requires this kind of input.

Comment: Thank you for the detail. I should have said "character vector" I think. I'm using quantmod to read the data and while your solution looks very similar it doesn't seem to be working. Perhaps the problem is that your solution puts the whole list in double quotes? Or each item in single quotes and quantmod can't read that? Is there a way to get it in exactly the form ("a", "b" ...)?

Comment: I edited my previous answer to show you how to insert double-quotes instead of single quotes (you just have to use the escape character `\ `). 
The "whole list" is *displayed* in "double quotes" only because it is a character. Still, I think that the input that your function requires might be actually a character vector. 
Maybe you could tell me which function from `quantmod` you are using. I know that at the beginning, R documentation might seem a bit confusing on expected inputs.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, I appreciate it. Above is my full code, which works, save for the fact that I have to type in all the tickers myself. As you suggested the tickers can be in single quotes, and still work with `getSymbols()` although the problem I'm running into is that the function you shared with me has `"DLX','SWK','AGN','SKX'..."` not `"'DLX','SWK','AGN','SKX'...` (notice the all encompassing quotes).

Comment: Ok. I think you definitely need a `character vector` (according to https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quantmod/quantmod.pdf). So no need to `paste`. It *should* work with `symbolList <- d[,2]` **unless** (that's my guess) `d[,2]` is a `factor` and not a `vector` (that happens if you build your `data.frame d` without the option `stringsAsFactors=F`). If I guess right, you have 3 options : 1) `symbolList <- as.character(d[,2])`, 2) `symbolList <- as.vector(d[,2]`, or 3) use `stringsAsFactors=F` when you build `d` (whether you use the `data.frame` method or `read.table` or `read.csv`).

Comment: `> symbolListt <- paste(c("'",paste(data[,2],collapse="','"),"'"),collapse="")
> symbolListt
[1] "'DLX','SWK','AGN','SKX','GE','ZOES','NVCR','FRT','ENLK','PYPL','TXMD','PLAY','NWL ','JAH ','MCRB ','RH'"
> symbolList = (sapply(symbolListt, function(x) gsub("\"", "", x)))                     > symbolList
 'DLX','SWK','AGN','SKX','GE','ZOES','NVCR','FRT','ENLK','PYPL','TXMD','PLAY','NWL ','JAH ','MCRB ','RH' 
"'DLX','SWK','AGN','SKX','GE','ZOES','NVCR','FRT','ENLK','PYPL','TXMD','PLAY','NWL ','JAH ','MCRB ','RH'"`

Comment: All your solutions got me very close, although I'm still not there. The bottom  code was the most tantalizing - it's what I want on the top row and not on the bottom but returns both!

Comment: The point on my previous answer was that, if it works with `symbolList <- c("DLX", "SWK", "AGN", "SKX", "GE", "ZOES", "NVCR", "FRT", "ENLK", "PYPL", "TXMD", "PLAY", "NWL", 
            "JAH")`, what you need is definitely a `character vector` (which is consistent with the doc). So, just replace this line with `symbolList <- as.character(d[,2])` and it *should* work.
If not, please give me the output of `class(d[,2])`.

Comment: Thank you! `symbolList <- as.character(d[,2])` does work - although strangely only for the first 12 tickers. I've tried re-arranging the tickers, and putting them in a different excel file and it's still only 12. It gives me an error that I don't get if I type the tickers in as well: `curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 400 Bad Request` and `Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection` with a _show traceback_ option. The rest of the error is in next comment. `class(d[,2])
[1] "character"`

Comment: `In addition: Warning messages:
1: In download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m,  :
  download had nonzero exit status
2: In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file '/var/folders/pw/68m35vl145z4pv0hszn5q3980000gn/T//RtmpNbvTac/file92d4e1f0a75': No such file or directory`